# How can I transfer touch focus to a PopupWindow before the user lifts their finger?

Tags: android, touch, android-screen

I have a View which will sometimes be occluded by a PopupWindow whose showing is triggered by touching the View. When this happens, I'd like to immediately transfer the stream of touch events to the PopupWindow. I can't just overlay a View in the same hierarchy because this happens in an IME covering a fraction of the screen area I need to capture gestures in.

I've tried sending an ACTION_CANCEL the the View's root container and dispatching my own ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent to the Popwindow. I've also tried overriding the bottom Window's root dispatchTouchEvent and dispatchGenericPointerEvent methods to do nothing and return false when the popup is active. Neither of these approaches worked.

If I simply lift my finger after the PopupWindow appears and put it down again, obviously I receive touch events no problem. I need to understand what happens when I do this that makes my original window relinquish touch focus and reset its dispatch state. Calling requestFocusFromTouch on my PopupWindow's content view when it appears and before I lift my finger returns false.

I'm quite happy to subclass and override where necessary, as I have full control over all the components involved.